# Need a slicker counterexample to show this inner product space is not Hilbert

Tags: hilbert-spaces, examples-counterexamples, inner-products

Let $F = \{f : [a, b] \to R,\ f \in C^1([a, b])\ \text{and}\ f(a) = 0\}$ with fourier coefficients as the inner product.

While $f_n(x) = \int_{0}^{x} g_n(y)dy$ is a cauchy sequence of functions on [-1, 1] where $g_n$ converges to sgn in the $L^2$ norm, and f_n(x) converges to the absolute value function for $x > 1/n$ in F's norm, I would like an example of a sequence of differentiable functions with supp(a,b] that converges to a function that is non zero on [a,b], which makes the solution much cleaner.

I tried a sequence of functions that have supp(0,1] and converge to a function with support on the compact interval [0,1], something along the lines of $(x - 1/n)^2$, but unfortunately $x^2$ of 0 is 0. I thought this would make it much easier, but I can't think of such a sequence.

Thanks

Comment: By Parseval this space is $C^1$ with the $L^2$ inner product, up to a constant factor. To make a counterexample, approximate a function that has a jump in the interior by $C^1$ functions.

Comment: You mean using the sgn function?

Comment: If your domain is $[-1,1]$ or something like that, then sgn is indeed a function with a jump in the interior. But it is not $C^1$. So you need to write down $C^1$ functions that are "converging" to it, and then show that the resulting sequence is Cauchy in your inner product but does not converge in that inner product to any $C^1$ function.

Comment: That's not very helpful because you're just restating what it means not to be Hilbert. I just thought [0, 1] would be easier to work with, but I'll try a  sequence on [-1,1] that converges to sgn

Comment: I'm doing a bit better, by suggesting a particular way to build a Cauchy sequence that is not convergent. There isn't a whole lot else I can do in the way of a hint, doing much more would just do the problem. You can also do this on $[0,1]$, just by approximating $f(x)=\begin{cases} 0 & x<1/2 \\ 1 & x \geq 1/2 \end{cases}$ or similar. The main point is that the right kind of discontinuity is a jump.

Comment: Also note that since you're explicitly talking about Fourier coefficients, you could potentially do it on the Fourier side; write down the Fourier expansion of, say, $\begin{cases} 1 & x \in [-\pi,-\pi/2] \\ 0 & x \in (-\pi/2,\pi/2) \\ 1 & x \in [\pi/2,\pi] \end{cases}$. Now write down a sequence of functions on the Fourier side which have better decay rates than that, and then reduce that improvement to zero in the limit.

Comment: Perhaps I should edit the question to better reflect what I am looking for. While your suggestion works, it is too much of a hindrance. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to do the thing you say you want to do (putting a discontinuity at an endpoint). In fact doing this will not really achieve the goal in your title, because if the discontinuity in the pointwise limit is at the *endpoint* then in fact the sequence will also converge in $L^2$ to a $C^1$ function. For example, $x^n$ on $[0,1]$ converges in $L^2$ to the zero function. You need the discontinuity to be in the interior so that it is "essential" (can't be removed by modification on a null set).

Comment: If the limiting function is non zero at the endpoint, then it's obviously not in F. Please refer to the edit.

Comment: $f_n(x) = \arctan(nx)$ converges to $f(x) \equiv \frac{\pi}{2}$ in $L^2[0,1]$.

Comment: You're missing my point. $L^2$ limits of *functions* rather than equivalence classes are highly non-unique. In particular, it is possible to make the function converge in $L^2$ to a function which is nonzero at the endpoint, but if it does then it will *also* converge in $L^2$ to a function which *is* zero at the endpoint.

Comment: Please refer to the edit before you comment again

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I'll try it and see if it works out easier.

Comment: I understood what you were asking for already, though now I see that for your purposes it is sufficient to "break out of $F$" by merely breaking the condition $f(a)=0$ without creating a discontinuity at that point. Indeed you can adapt the $x^n$ example that I mentioned to make it do the same job: look at $1-(1-x)^n$, which converges in $L^2$ to $f(x)=1$.

Comment: That was the first sentence of my original question. But I'll try your example as well.